# What is the optional argument in C# interpolated string for?

Tags: c#, .net, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

Interpolated strings is one of the new features of C# 6.0.

According to MSDN, the syntax of the embedded C# expressions can contain an optional, comma-separated value, deemed as `<optional-comma-field-width>` in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx).

Unfortunately I didn't find what this field is for.

From its name one might think that this value sets the maximal size of the "interpolated" field, but when I try the following expression:

```
var p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
Console.WriteLine($"Process name is {p.ProcessName, 5}");
```

I get the following output:

```
Process name is LINQPad.UserQuery
```

Comment: What happens if you specify a string whose length is less than the field width?

Comment: The string interpolation does in this particular case is replacing `p.ProcessName` with `0` and passing `p.ProcessName` as an argument to `string.Format`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's the *minimum* width to use for that field, not the *maximum*.  Since your string is longer than the 5 characters you specify for the width, the field is extended to the length of your string.  You'll see the difference more dramatically with a longer width:

```
var p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
$"Process name is {p.ProcessName, 50}".Dump();
```

yields:

```
Process name is                                  LINQPad.UserQuery
```

A positive field size is right-justified; a negative field size is left-justified.

The documentation is better on the [Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) page of MSDN:

> The optional alignment component is a signed integer indicating the
>   preferred formatted field width. If the value of alignment is less
>   than the length of the formatted string, alignment is ignored and the
>   length of the formatted string is used as the field width. The
>   formatted data in the field is right-aligned if alignment is positive
>   and left-aligned if alignment is negative. If padding is necessary,
>   white space is used. The comma is required if alignment is specified.

Answer (score 20):

The number is the *alignment*, documented in the Alignment Component [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx).

> The formatted data in the field is right-aligned if alignment is
>   positive and left-aligned if alignment is negative.

In your example, *alignment* will pad the `p.ProcessName` with spaces if it is less than `5` characters long.  Where string length is less than the absolute value of *alignment* (like in your example), *alignment* has no effect.

**Example**

```cs
var text = "MyText";
Console.WriteLine($"x{text}x");
Console.WriteLine($"x{text, 3}x");
Console.WriteLine($"x{text, 10}x");
Console.WriteLine($"x{text, -10}x");
```

**Result**

```
xMyTextx
xMyTextx
x    MyTextx
xMyText    x
```