# Formatting strings in C#

Tags: c#, formatexception

I'm trying to format array elements to look like a table with some columns to have right alignment and some left as shown in [Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) article (or [What is the optional argument in C# interpolated string for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620851/what-is-the-optional-argument-in-c-sharp-interpolated-string-for))

Why I'm getting `FormatException` on call to `Console.WriteLine`?

Here is sample that demonstrates this:

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication97
{
    class Program
    {
        public struct User
        {
            public string Name;
            public byte Age;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            User[] Bar = new User[2];
            Bar[0].Name = "Jan Kowalski";
            Bar[0].Age = 32;
            Bar[1].Name = "Piotr Nowak";
            Bar[1].Age = 56;
            for (int i = 0; i < Bar.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0 , -15} | { 1,  5}", Bar[i].Name, Bar[i].Age);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Value "Name" should be on the left side (alignment -15), "Age" should be on the right side (alignment 5).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interesting - the formatter seems to be picky about excess whitespace in format strings.  This worked for me:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0, -15} | {1, 5}", Bar[i].Name, Bar[i].Age);
```

Comment: Saw it also: `Console.WriteLine("{0 , -15} | { 1,  5}", Bar[i].Name, Bar[i].Age);`

Comment: It appears that anything that supports [Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx), such as `Console.WriteLine` and `string.Format`,  have this whitespace issue where they give a `FormatException` if there's spaces after any opening bracket `{` (it seems to support spaces anywhere else, however). But note that string interpolation doesn't have this issue: `Console.WriteLine($"{    Bar[i].Name, -15} | {     Bar[i].Age,  5}");` works fine for me.